# In android how to programmatically list the apps that use Data connection?

Tags: java, android

can anyone please tell me in android, is it possible to access the list of application names that are using Data connection in background/foreground? If possible how?

note: I came to know it is possible to access the Total data consumption in bytes by reading TX/RX files. But i couldn't find which applications are using the data connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible with a little work. You'll need to use the PackageManager to get the permissions each Application requires. Then you can simply filter the applications based on those permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, by looking at your comment what I understood is I need to list out all the installed applications and get the permission used by them and if any of them having permission USING_INTERNET and if it is running I need to assume that this application is consumng Data connection. Please correct me If I am wrong with my understanding.

Comment: But unfortunately I have to collect accurate data, the app running and which is having Internet permission is does not mean actually it is comsuming data. And also my requiremnt is to collect only Data connection using apps not wifi. :(